# How do I make the camera stay within a sphere?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I can make the camera move the way I want, but I need it to be confined to within the 3D hollow sphere that I created. Currently the player can fly the camera out of the game area.

I've tried parenting the camera to a spherical game object, but the camera still leaves the game area but the sphere stays inside.

This was my attempt at using the BoundingSphere method to keep the camera inside the sphere.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SphericalBoundary : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 pos;
    public float r;

    void Start()
    {
        BoundingSphere();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        BoundingSphere();
    }

    public void BoundingSphere()
    {
            pos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            r = (100); 
    }    



}



============================================================================
============================================================================

This is the script that makes the camera fly around. Works perfectly.



    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class CameraFlight : MonoBehaviour
    {

        /*
        EXTENDED FLYCAM
            Desi Quintans (CowfaceGames.com), 17 August 2012.
            Based on FlyThrough.js by Slin (http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/FlyThrough), 17 May 2011.

        LICENSE
            Free as in speech, and free as in beer.

        FEATURES
            WASD/Arrows:    Movement
                      Q:    Climb
                      E:    Drop
                          Shift:    Move faster
                        Control:    Move slower
                            End:    Toggle cursor locking to screen (you can also press Ctrl+P to toggle play mode on and off).
        */

        public float cameraSensitivity = 90;
        public float climbSpeed = 4;
        public float normalMoveSpeed = 10;
        public float slowMoveFactor = 0.25f;
        public float fastMoveFactor = 3;

        private float rotationX = 0.0f;
        private float rotationY = 0.0f;

        void Start()
        {
           // Screen.lockCursor = true;
        }

        void Update()
        {
            rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * cameraSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * cameraSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, -90, 90);

            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationX, Vector3.up);
            transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationY, Vector3.left);

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift))
            {
                transform.position += transform.forward * (normalMoveSpeed * fastMoveFactor) * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position += transform.right * (normalMoveSpeed * fastMoveFactor) * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightControl))
            {
                transform.position += transform.forward * (normalMoveSpeed * slowMoveFactor) * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position += transform.right * (normalMoveSpeed * slowMoveFactor) * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                transform.position += transform.forward * normalMoveSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position += transform.right * normalMoveSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime;
            }


            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q)) { transform.position += transform.up * climbSpeed * Time.deltaTime; }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) { transform.position -= transform.up * climbSpeed * Time.deltaTime; }

            //if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.End))
            //{
            //    Screen.lockCursor = (Screen.lockCursor == false) ? true :][1] 

false;
        //}
    }
}
```

No errors are showing up. During play the player can fly the camera out of the sphere but I want them confined to the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must look your camera position on every frame and also check if it's going out of bound of the sphere here is some code which might help you(it is not tested)

```
public class TestScriptForStackOverflow : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform CameraTrans, SphereTrans;

private float _sphereRadius;


void Start() {
    //if we are talking about sphere its localscale.x,y,z values are always equal
    _sphereRadius = SphereTrans.localScale.x / 2; 
}


void Update() {
    if (IsOutsideTheSphere(_sphereRadius, CameraTrans.position, SphereTrans.position)) {
        //lets find direction of camera from sphere center
        Vector3 direction = (CameraTrans.position - SphereTrans.position).normalized;
        //this is bound point for specific direction which is point is on the end of the radius
        Vector3 boundPos = SphereTrans.position + direction * _sphereRadius;
        //finally assign bound position to camera to stop it to pierce the sphere bounds
        CameraTrans.position = boundPos;
    }
}

private bool IsOutsideTheSphere(float sphereRadius, Vector3 cameraPosition, Vector3 sphereCenterPosition) {

    //distance betweeen cameraPosition and sphereCenterPosition
    float distanceBetween = (cameraPosition - sphereCenterPosition).magnitude;
    //returns true if distance between sphere center and camera position is longer then sphere radius
    return distanceBetween > sphereRadius;

}
```

If there is something you don't understand ask me in comments

Comment: Thanks for responding! This code is close to what I need. This script seems to lock the camera at a certain distance from the spheres center, not allowing movement closer to or further from the center. I want the camera to move freely within the sphere, but not be able to move outside it. I think I can make that happen, I'll work on it today.

Comment: Good luck. I think this script can handle that